# ASP.NET Performance Counter value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performancecounter

I am building a library project that will record the values of ASP.NET Performance Counters when used with a ASP.NET Project. But when I try to run the following code -

```
var  _RequestsPerSecond = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications",  "Requests/sec", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
_RequestsInApplicationQueueValue = _RequestsInApplicationQueue.NextValue();
```

It gives me the error iis express does not exist in this category. Any suggestions.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName as   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID.Replace('/', '_')

Comment: I had to add a dependency for system.web in my library to do this. Is there any way to do this without adding any dependency.?

Comment: may be you can refer this blog to get instance name by process id:https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Sep/27/Capturing-Performance-Counter-Data-for-a-Process-by-Process-Id

Comment: this works fine for ASP.NET Application Performance counters but again throws error for ASP.NET Counters.